# nopcommerce: telerik grid link item cannot find parameter (Id is not defined)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, telerik, telerik-grid, telerik-mvc, nopcommerce

I have added new menu, new controller and new view in my nop.Admin project. What i want is to bind Edit link inside Rad grid in nop.Admin. my code is.

```
            @(Html.Telerik().Grid<Nop.Admin.Models.AuthorizeWorkshops.RegistrationModel>()
              .Name("ProductRegistration-grid")
              .Columns(columns =>
              {                      
                  columns.Bound(x => x.RegisteredProducts.Make);
                  columns.Bound(x => x.RegisteredProducts.Model);
                  columns.Bound(x => x.RegisteredProducts.Year);
                  columns.Bound(x => x.RegisteredProducts.CC);
                  columns.Bound(x => x.RegisteredProducts.AuthorizedWorkshop);
                  columns.Bound(x => x.RegisteredProducts.PurchaseDate);
                  columns.Bound(x => x.RegisteredProducts.InoiceNo);
                  columns.Bound(x => x.RegisteredProducts.SerialNo);

                  columns.Bound(x => x.RegisteredProducts.Id)
                    .Template(x => Html.ActionLink(T("Admin.Common.Edit").Text, "Edit", new { Id = x.RegisteredProducts.Id }))
                    .ClientTemplate("<a href=\"Edit/<#= Id #>\">" + T("Admin.Common.Edit").Text + "</a>")
                    .Width(50)
                    .Centered()
                    .HeaderTemplate(T("Admin.Common.Edit").Text)
                    .Filterable(false);
              })
              .Pageable(settings => settings.PageSize(gridPageSize).Position(GridPagerPosition.Both))
              .DataBinding(dataBinding => dataBinding.Ajax().Select("List", "ProductRegistration"))
              .EnableCustomBinding(true))
```

****if i exclude following code****

```
                  columns.Bound(x => x.RegisteredProducts.Id)
                    .Template(x => Html.ActionLink(T("Admin.Common.Edit").Text, "Edit", new { Id = x.RegisteredProducts.Id }))
                    .ClientTemplate("<a href=\"Edit/<#= Id #>\">" + T("Admin.Common.Edit").Text + "</a>")
                    .Width(50)
                    .Centered()
                    .HeaderTemplate(T("Admin.Common.Edit").Text)
```

Rad Grid in View works fine and return me all records. ****but if i continue with same**** i get following error.

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Id is not defined
```

Please Help me for this issue. thanks.

Comment: <a href=\"Edit?Id=/<#= Id #>\">"

Comment: unfortunately, or luckily it is working in other views in same fashion mentioned above. but those were developed by previous developer, and i am unable to identify how?

Comment: btw, this case is not helpful. not working

Answer (score 0):

It took my 5 hours to identify that what was issue behind the scene. Actaully i was using model which was returning multiple models. so i just replaced

```
.ClientTemplate("<a href=\"Edit/<#= Id #>\">" + T("Admin.Common.Edit").Text + "</a>")
```

**** WITH ****

```
.ClientTemplate("<a href=\"Edit/<#= RegisteredProducts.Id #>\">" + T("Admin.Common.Edit").Text + "</a>")
```

and it worked.

Thanks GOD.